# Scala warning match may not be exhaustive

Tags: scala, compiler-warnings

I am somewhat new to Scala. Following is my code.

```
Option(Session.get().getAttribute("player")) match {
  case None => {
    val player = new Player(user.getEmail, user.getNickname).createOrGet
    Session.get().setAttribute("player", player)
  }
}
```

I get the following warning when compiling

```
Warning:(35, 11) match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: Some(_)
    Option(Session.get().getAttribute("player")) match {
          ^
```

How do I fix this? Is there a way to rewrite the code to avoid the warning?(I am using Scala version 2.10.2)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When pattern matching, you should account for all possible cases or provide a "fallback" (case _ => ... ). `Option` can be `Some` or `None`, but you're only matching against the `None` case.

If `Session.get().getAttribute("player")` returned `Some(player)` you would get a `MatchError` (exception).

Since your code seems to not be returning anything, I would re-write this without the `match` at all, and just check `isEmpty`.

```
if(Option(Session.get().getAttribute("player")).isEmpty) {
    val player = new Player(user.getEmail, user.getNickname).createOrGet
    Session.get().setAttribute("player", player)
}
```

Though this isn't really much different than checking `Session.get().getAttribute("player") == null`.

Comment: For style, I would `Session.get.getAttr("foo") match { case null => case _ => }`. Easier to read. Or `Option(...) orElse alt`. Or `Some(Session.get) filter (_.getAttr("foo") != null) orElse (s => Some(s.setAttr("", x)))` or similar.

Answer (score 3):

You're matching only the case `None`, a more correct way would be to match the `Some(something)` case too. `Option(...)` can yield `None` or `Some(_)`, hence the error.

In this case a better solution to what you are trying to do would simply be:

```
if(Session.get().getAttribute("player") == null){
    val player = new Player(user.getEmail, user.getNickname).createOrGet
    Session.get().setAttribute("player", player)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include a `Some` case:

```
Option(Session.get().getAttribute("player")) match {
  case Some(value) => // do something here
  case None => {
    val player = new Player(user.getEmail, user.getNickname).createOrGet
    Session.get().setAttribute("player", player)
  }
}
```

Comment: But I don't need to do anything for the `Some` case. At least that's what I think. Based on the code, (which adds the player to the session object if it's not already there) what kind of work should be done in the `Some(__` case?

Comment: If you don't need to do anything for the `Some` case why are you using `Option` at all?

Comment: You're just unnecessarily creating an object to do a null-check.