# Warning Match may not be exhaustive

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I was trying out below code:

```
  val set1 = Set(1,2,3,4,5,67,8)
  val TRUE_BOOLEAN = true
  val FALSE_BOOLEAN = false
  set1.contains(4) match {
    case TRUE_BOOLEAN => println("Element found")
    case FALSE_BOOLEAN => println("Element not found")
  }
```

But, when i am trying to run it in `IntelliJ`, it is giving below warning in `Messages` tab:

```
Warning:(11, 16) match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following inputs: false, true
  set1.contains(4) match {
```

Whereas, if i use `true` and `false` instead of `TRUE_BOOLEAN` and `FALSE_BOOLEAN`, i am not getting any warning.

```
set1.contains(4) match {
    case true => println("Element found")
    case false => println("Element not found")
  }
```

Can someone please explain the reason for this warning and why does it goes away with `true` and `false`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala warning match may not be exhaustive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709101/scala-warning-match-may-not-be-exhaustive)

Comment: Even if I specify the type explicitly, I still get a warning. Scastie also gives the same warning, regardless of whether the type annotations are present or not. Not reproducible. Consider re-tagging it explicitly as intellij-bug.

Comment: @Yogesh How is this a duplicate of what you've proposed?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin as mentioned duplicate URL,  `in pattern matching you should account for all possible cases or provide a "fallback"` if you add `case _` in match then it not show warning.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin yes, you are right...I am also getting warning even after adding type explicitly. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It produces a warning, because it cannot guarantee that the match is exhaustive.

Indeed, when embedded in the right context, your code throws a match error at runtime:

```
class Foo {
  val set1 = Set(1,2,3,4,5,67,8)
  val TRUE_BOOLEAN = true
  val FALSE_BOOLEAN = false
  set1.contains(4) match {
    case TRUE_BOOLEAN => println("Element found")
    case FALSE_BOOLEAN => println("Element not found")
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  override val TRUE_BOOLEAN = false
}

new Bar // scala.MatchError: true (of class java.lang.Boolean)
```

so the warning is *correct*, and not merely an over-conservative estimate. Since every Scala script is implicitly embedded into some "class-like" wrapper, it also works in Scala scripts in exactly the same way, even if you don't wrap it in a `Foo`-class.

If you set both variables to `final`, then constant propagation works properly, and no warning is emitted:

```
class Foo {
  val set1 = Set(1,2,3,4,5,67,8)
  final val TRUE_BOOLEAN = true
  final val FALSE_BOOLEAN = false
  set1.contains(4) match {
    case TRUE_BOOLEAN => println("Element found")
    case FALSE_BOOLEAN => println("Element not found")
  }
}
```

compiles just fine, no warnings.